# Magento 2 grid filter(active filter) lost on page reload

Tags: magento2.2, attributes, filter, product-grid

I am using Webkul Marketplace ext. and they have issue on active filters.

after filtering whenever reloading the page or visiting other page and backing on the filter page then filter get losses and it opens normally(without any filter).

actually there is separate dashboard for the seller where sellers can manage orders,products etc.so these UI's are some similarity like  admin.

**Snippet:-**

**After Filter:-** it works as expected.

[image]

**Revisiting on Filter Page:-** Filter gets lossed and act as normally.

[image]

I R&D and they suggested to use **"bookmark"** used but no luck.

please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried raising it with Webkul?

Comment: actually,the support period is over so can't contact them.